# Slow select when select_type DERIVED

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have two servers: production and local.

One (local) use 5.7.35
And (production) other 5.7.36

Databases is the same. (mysqldump from production to local)

And one SQL which works fine locally but is very slow in production

```
SELECT culture_prices.*
FROM   (SELECT culture_prices.*,
               ( culture_prices.nds_grn_cents - IF(distance_m.distance > 50000,
(
Nds_distance_cost(distance_m.distance)
),
                                 10000)
) AS
nds_grn_cents_with_delivery,
distance_m.distance
AS distance_meters
FROM   `culture_prices`
INNER JOIN `cultures`
ON `cultures`.`id` = `culture_prices`.`culture_id`
INNER JOIN `elevators`
ON `elevators`.`id` = `culture_prices`.`elevator_id`
INNER JOIN `distance_m`
ON `distance_m`.`elevator_id` = `elevators`.`id`
INNER JOIN `cities`
ON `cities`.`id` = `distance_m`.`city_id`
LEFT JOIN org_cultures cul_1
ON culture_prices.org_culture_id = cul_1.id
WHERE  ( culture_prices.nds_grn_cents > 0 )
AND `culture_prices`.`is_searchable` = 1
AND ( cul_1.is_active = '1' )
AND ( cities.id = 1503 )
ORDER  BY is_check_price ASC,
nds_grn_cents_with_delivery DESC) AS culture_prices
WHERE  `culture_prices`.`culture_id` = 24
```

On local server  query time is **0.0471**
Select_type is **SIMPLE** and used **index_merge**

EXPLAIN
[image]

On the production server  query time is more than  **5.0589**
Select_type is **DERIVED** and  **not** used **index_merge**

EXPLAIN

[image]

Why do I have more than 100x slower SQL on production?
Configuration are almost identical
Thanks.

Comment: I cannot answer the question. Sorry. But here are some remarks: You are using an outer join on org_cultures, but then in your `WHERE` clause you have `cul_1.is_active = '1'`, thus dismissing all outer joined rows and turning the join into an inner join. Do you want an outer join? Or do you actually want an inner join? Then, the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is superfluous, because subquery results are unordered data sets by definition. Then, why is this a subquery at all? Why don't you apply `cp.culture_id = 24` directly? And `JOIN cultures` is superfluous. You don't use the table in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the same name for the derived table as a real table.  It is terribly confusing, at least to me, maybe also to the Optimizer.

Get rid of the outer query and move the test for id=24 into the inner query.

The `LEFT JOIN cul_1` is really an `INNER JOIN` (because of `is_active=1`).

Why `JOIN` to `cities` only to insist that `id=1503`?  You should probably get rid of the JOIN.

Suggested indexes:

```
culture_prices:  INDEX(is_searchable, culture_id, nds_grn_cents,  elevator_id, org_culture_id)
distance_m:  INDEX(elevator_id,  distance, city_id)
cul_1:  INDEX(is_active, id)
```

"Index merge intersect" is almost always indicates the need for a longer composite index *instead of* the slower "Index merge".  I hope I have provided such in the list above.

As for why the two versions are not the same speed -- Clearly something changed in the Optimizer; it is sad that it is slower in the newer version; perhaps my suggestions will make both faster.

If you need more assistance, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...
```